# Is OkHttpClent thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, okhttp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB0b2.png)

Okhttp uses OkHttpClent to send requests.

can I use the same OkHttpClent instance to requests in different Threads ?

Comment: Please write your code into your post not as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48532860/9246764

Answer (score 2):

Yes. OkHttpClient is thread safe, and the use case you describe is expected.  Do **not** create a new client instance per thread.

But at the same time, consuming a single Response from multiple threads is probably unwise.

See docs here https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/#okhttpclients-should-be-shared